# Field-level validation on any change

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, validation

Hibernate's validation (`hibernate-validator`) does validation when `@Entity` is being persisted (before). That is not enough as I want seamless validation on business layer.

So the goal is to validate fields on any change - meaning that e.g. `@NotBlank` applied to field will throw an exception whenever I call `this.field = value;` with blank variable (without calling outside validation service, so basically an aspect).

Based on my knowledge on AspectJ, there should be an **existing** possibility for javax.validation annotation applied on **fields** to be making them **on-change sensitive**.

My question is - what tools do I use and how do I configure them or what am I even looking for (I have no knowledge on this spec nor its implementations)?

My backend stack is Spring (Boot) with JPA (Hibernate) that ships with mentioned hibernate-validator, what else do I need to make my goal work with least code/config?

***EDIT***

To give example:

```
@NotBlank
private String name;

public void setName1(String name)
{
    System.out.println("CHANGING 1");
    this.name = name;
    System.out.println("PASSED 1");
}

public void setName2(String name)
{
    System.out.println("CHANGING 2");
    this.name = name;
    System.out.println("PASSED 2");
}
```

...with call:

```
public void test()
{
    String newName = "  ";
    entity.setName1(newName);
    entity.setName2(newName);
}
```

Should print:

```
CHANGING 1
```

and:

```
public void test2()
{
    String newName = "  "l
    try { this.entity.setName1(newName); } catch (Exception e) { }
    this.entity.setName2(newName);
}
```

Should print:

```
CHANGING 1
CHANGING 2
```

I thought of using private setter like:

```
private void setNamePriv(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

private void setName1(String name) // or setName2
{
    this.setNamePriv(name);
}
```

...but then I still don't know how to make name argument checked for `@NotBlank` when method is ran. Apparently syntax:

```
private void setNamePriv(@NotBlank String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}
```

...is supported, but what library/configuration actually would make it work (currently used hibernate-validator doesn't do it by default).

Then again - using private setters introduces more boilerplate code across all entity classes and I am already using lombok to make those setters. Would have to make public setters with lombok and private myself or other way around.

***What technology (library/config) am I looking for here?***

***EDIT 2***

To clarify even more - I do know the reasons why it's not supported out-of-box:

- Spring AOP uses proxies and does so only on `@Bean`s (which are proxied).
- For validation to take place `@Bean` (e.g. `@Component` or `@Service`) must also have `@Validated`.

As described that is a no-go, since e.g. `@Entity` is not a `@Bean`. As mentioned, I am probably looking for AspectJ solution but apparently there is nothing I could find. I don't think writing own aspect is that hard for this, but how come i can't find existing solution?